# Subpackages does not install in R

Tags: r

I have just upgraded to R4.0.0 and Rstudio  1.2.5042

Now i have to update the packages i use. So I run the code

```
install.packages ("tidyverse")
```

Its fine.. it installs.. but a load of the subpackages does not install and i have to do this manually. Does anyone know whats happening?

[image: Tidyverse in installed but not subpackages]

Update: Now R is blocking my directory?

[image: Blocking of directory]

Comment: Try `install.packges("tidyverse", dependencies=TRUE)`.

Comment: no.... it still comes up with all the subpackages...

Comment: You are using packages that were built for an earlier version of R.  Run `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt=TRUE)` to get everything up to date.

Comment: Nope.. i made a new directory.. and now it somehow is working.. its wacko this process.. 5 hours wasted

Comment: How i got another problem.. and this seems to rhyme.. i cannot access the R directory from R...Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library' .. i have a strong feeling something is wrong here..... ( i am administrator)